# Pandas : Adding list of columns to a new columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A part Of my dataframe is columns of some medications like this:

```
Atenolol 50 mg  Atorvastatin    Azathioprine 50 mg
1   0   0
1   0   0
0   0   1
0   1   0
0   0   1
1   0   0
0   1   1
0   1   0
```

I want to create a new column `Drugs`, that include name of used medications, like below:

```
Drugs
Atenolol 50 mg
Atenolol 50 mg
Azathioprine 50 mg
Atorvastatin
Azathioprine 50 mg
Atenolol 50 mg
Atorvastatin, Azathioprine 50 mg
Atorvastatin
```

I tried to use pd.apply() and lamda functions, but I have no Idea how to do this correctly:

```
for i in range(227, 498):
    Drugs = df[df.columns[i]].apply(lambda x: Drugs.append(df.columns(i) if x == 1 else continue))
```

227 to 498 is the columns that include medications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df['Drugs'] = df.dot(df.columns + ', ').str.strip(', ')
```